# Spring-Data Calling Save on Entity from Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using `Spring Data` within `Spring Boot`. I have a simple controller method that accepts an instance of an entity I'd like to update in my database. However, after calling `repository.save()` the object isn't persisted, however, if I query for the object (from the Id of the incoming entity) I have no problem, and the update persists.

Also the HTTP response is a 405 that the method doesn't work?

Controller:

```
@Transactional
public class AccountController {
    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody Account updateAccount(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody Account account) {
        return accountService.updateAndValidateAccountProfile(account);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Override
public Account updateAndValidateAccountProfile(Account account) {
    // calling findOne() returns the object ... and the save() works fine
    //Account currentAccount = accountRepository.findOne(account.getId());
    return accountRepository.save(account);
}
```

Repository:

```
interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {

}
```

Is there something about the way I need to identify the object to `Spring Data`. I see the `select` statements fire out of `hibernate`, and I know the `merge` should happened on the primary key (id) within the Spring Data call to `.save()` - so I *shouldn't* need to query the object and manually assign the updated values correct??

Comment: I don't think the code compiles even as you present it ("crrentAccount" is undefined), so maybe we are missing something important? Also, a 405 response should mean the controller method was never called, so no surprise if the updates are not persisted. Finally, your id parameter in the controller method is never used?

Comment: Hey Dave, so that was something I forgot to change in my sample code, I was calling `accountRepository.save(account)` and having the same issue. In reference to the `id` parameter, it was just to keep with the spirit of a `Restful` URL structure. I fixed the `405` by moving the `@ResponseBody` annotation...so I get a 200, but the update isn't persisting?

Comment: Your `Account` object is a `@RequestBody` so it is created by an `HttpMessageConverter` (JSON maybe?) and is never explicitly associated with the JPA `EntityManager`. Spring Data should take care of that ([per the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)). When you said "after calling repository.save() the object isn't persisted" what did you mean? How were you testing that? Maybe the transaction wasn't committed yet when you queried?

Comment: Thanks @DaveSyer, I think I figured it out! I was actually attempting to update a relationship object that wasn't correctly annotated...updates to the actual object are being persisted in a method I made, but the child-type say on a `@OneToOne` relationship aren't ... because JPA/Hibernate didn't understand them correctly. I shouldn't have blamed the controller!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you enabled transaction management? You need to use `@EnableTransactionManagement` on your config class otherwise `@Transactional` has no effect.

A spring tutorial on [Managing Transactions](https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/)

As a side note: making the controller layer transactional is usually not a good idea, especially when you have a proper separation of controller, service and repository layers. Consider moving `@Transactional` into the service layer.

Since you are using JPA, also make sure you have a `JpaTransactionManager` configured:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
}
```

You might try extending the JpaRepository interface instead of CrudRepository then you can use `saveAndFlush(entity)` to make sure the changes are immediately flushed after merge.

Comment: I added `@EnableTransactionManagement` (above `@EnableAutoConfiguration`) and than also moved the `@Transactional` annotation inside the service layer. Both with and without `@Transactional` the method in the service-layer does the same thing. In the tutorial they use JDBC instead of JPA / Repository definitions as well, I don't know if that changes the behavior?

Comment: then TX management is probably fine. so you are using JPA, I edit my answer with another hint you could try.

Comment: DJust for the record: `@EnableTransactionManagement` should be on by default with Spring Boot and JPA (no harm if you add it yourself, just that it wasn't the problem).

Comment: Added the `saveAndFlush()` didn't get any new results

Comment: another thing related to TX management: do you have a `JpaTransactionManager` configured in your context?

Comment: @gadget don't think so - I thought all this was wrapped into the Spring Boot `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

Comment: Spring Boot will provide the transaction manager, so there is one there (otherwise the error would be obvious).

Comment: I'm going to give this one to @gadget for all his work attempting to help me out of my own stupidity